# IIS Not Loading Some Pages

Tags: iis, request, timeout, iis-8

Website in question:
http://redbirdled.com/ (very apparent)

So RedBirdLED mainly loads fine but hangs many other times if I leave it alone and try to load a new page. The only way to get it to load is to try and load it again and it immediately loads after that. This is not a client issue as many people are reporting the problem. I've tried a few things such as idle-timeout and weird stuff with IIS already but it didn't help.

Overall the thing I am getting is that if I try to load something, it will wait and simply timeout from waiting. However if I press the button again immediately it is very likely to instantly load without issue. What is going on and is there any way I can trace the issue?

I'm going to assume it has little to do with idling unless it is possible to idle within 10 seconds... This issue is random at times. I don't understand what is happening.

Visit http://sole-revival.com/ and let me know if there are any issues. For me personally, the website runs PERFECTLY and without issue. That's the weirdest part. Some pools hang and some don't? I have never modified these pools from the default setting until tonight as I try to resolve the issue.

I'm using IIS 8.0 on Win Server 2012.

Comment: Have you tried to change the IIS app pool config(classic <=> integrated)? It sometimes helps when encountering a mysterious IIS behavour.

Comment: Nope, I'll keep that in mind though. I want to let you know that I figured out it was Cloudflare causing the issue and that all I had to do was disable Cloudflare's features other than the DNS (not sure which feature caused it) but all websites under Cloudflare on my server had the issue. Keep that in mind for any future problems.